# Properly passing data on stdin to a command and receiving data from stdout of that command in golang

Tags: go

I have the following program:

```
package main

import "bytes"
import "io"
import "log"
import "os"
import "os/exec"
import "time"

func main() {
    runCatFromStdinWorks(populateStdin("aaa\n"))
    runCatFromStdinWorks(populateStdin("bbb\n"))
}

func populateStdin(str string) func(io.WriteCloser) {
    return func(stdin io.WriteCloser) {
        defer stdin.Close()
        io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewBufferString(str))
    }
}

func runCatFromStdinWorks(populate_stdin_func func(io.WriteCloser)) {
    cmd := exec.Command("cat")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    go populate_stdin_func(stdin)
    go func() {
            // Removing the following lines allow some output
            // to be fetched from cat's stdout sometimes
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
    }()
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

When running in a loop, I get no results, like so:

```
$ while true; do go run cat_thingy.go; echo ; done



^C
```

This result comes after installing golang-go on an Ubuntu 12.04 from apt in a virtual machine (go version go1).  I have not been able to replicate on a go installation on a Macbook Air (go version go1.0.3). It seems to be some kind of race condition. In fact, if I put a sleep(1*time.Second), I never see the issue at the expense of a random sleep in my code.

Is there something I am doing wrong in the code, or is this a bug? If it is a bug, has it been fixed?

**UPDATE: Possible Clue**

I found that the Command.Wait will close the pipes for communicating to/from the cat subprocess even if they still have unread data. I am not really sure the about the proper way to handle that. I guess I could create a channel to notify when the writing to stdin is done, but I would still need to know if the cat process has ended to make sure that nothing else was going to be written to its stdout pipe. I know that I can use cmd.Process.Wait to determine when the process ends, but is it safe to then call cmd.Wait?

**UPDATE: Getting Closer**

Here's a new cut at the code. I believe that this works as far as writing to stdin and reading from the stdout. I think I can make it properly stream the data (instead of buffering it all) if I replace the io.Copy from the stdout handling goroutine without something that streams.

```
package main

import "bytes"
import "fmt"
import "io"
import "log"
import "os/exec"
import "runtime"

const inputBufferBlockLength = 3*64*(2<<10) // enough to be bigger than 2x the pipe buffer of 64KiB
const numInputBlocks = 6

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(5)
    runCatFromStdin(populateStdin(numInputBlocks))
}

func populateStdin(numInputBlocks int) func(io.WriteCloser, chan bool) {
    return func(stdin io.WriteCloser) {
        defer stdin.Close()
        repeatedByteBases := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
        for i := 0; i < numInputBlocks; i++ {
          repeatedBytes := bytes.NewBufferString(repeatedByteBases[i]).Bytes()
          fmt.Printf("%s\n", repeatedBytes)
          io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewReader(bytes.Repeat(repeatedBytes, inputBufferBlockLength)))
        }
    }
}

func runCatFromStdin(populate_stdin_func func(io.WriteCloser)) {
    cmd := exec.Command("cat")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    go populate_stdin_func(stdin)
    output_done_channel := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        out_bytes := new(bytes.Buffer)
        io.Copy(out_bytes, stdout)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", out_bytes)
        fmt.Println(out_bytes.Len())
        fmt.Println(inputBufferBlockLength*numInputBlocks)
        output_done_channel <- true
    }()
    <-output_done_channel
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version of your first code which works.  Note the addition of the sync.WaitGroup to make sure you finish with the sending and receiving go routines before closing the command.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    runCatFromStdinWorks(populateStdin("aaa\n"))
    runCatFromStdinWorks(populateStdin("bbb\n"))
}

func populateStdin(str string) func(io.WriteCloser) {
    return func(stdin io.WriteCloser) {
        defer stdin.Close()
        io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewBufferString(str))
    }
}

func runCatFromStdinWorks(populate_stdin_func func(io.WriteCloser)) {
    cmd := exec.Command("cat")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        populate_stdin_func(stdin)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

(This is just another way of saying what @peterSO said though ;-)

Comment: This isn't just another way of saying what @peterSO said. It actually handles the pipe buffers correctly since the input to cat is handled in a separate goroutine from the output. I also think that the WaitGroups is a little nicer than the channel I used to do the synchronization. I still find it relatively confusing that the pipes are closed as a side effect of the cmd.Wait(). It really confusing because it doesn't happen until after the process ends.