# Answer to password shell prompt in golang

Tags: linux, git, go

I am searching for a way to answer to a shell password prompt in golang.

like :

```
bussiere@kus:~/Workspace/rteest$ ./passwordtest.sh
Password :
```

I would like to enter the password automatically with my token in golang after launching a shell command / script ...

I've made some script that get a one time token with mfa if everything is ok (in golang). So i need to enter the tempory token to a linux password prompt.

I know that there is the expect command but i would like to compile my program to embed it and have minimal depency.

Thanks and regards

edit thks to @nevermore i've tried this (but it doesn't work) : https://play.golang.org/p/Ffm3q5h636

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    cmdb := "git"
    args := "clone https://bb@gitlab.com/bb/fzgs.git"
cmd := exec.Command(cmdb, args)
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
log.Fatal(err)
}

go func() {
defer stdin.Close()
io.WriteString(stdin, "QSRDFGHJfZERTYU")
}()

out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)

}
```

it gives me this :

```
2017/05/12 20:42:36 exit status 1
exit status 1
```

edit bis  :

```
    cmdb := "git"
    args := "https://bb@gitlab.com/bb/fzgs.git"
cmd := exec.Command(cmdb, "clone", args)
```

it asks for the password :

Password for 'https://bb@gitlab.com':

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using ssh key based authentication? I assume this is for some sort of deployment-related application. You can generate deployment keys with read-only permission in some git services.

Answer (score 4):

If a user is asked for a password in their shell, you can use golang to **write to the io.Writer** that is `os.Stdin`

[Properly passing data on stdin to a command and receiving data from stdout of that command in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803425/properly-passing-data-on-stdin-to-a-command-and-receiving-data-from-stdout-of-th)

**`os.Stdin`** is a `os.File` created by

```
NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/stdin")
```

And the password prompt will be reading from this file

You can execute `./passwordtest.sh` as in your question, and then write the password to `os.Stdin`, and the bash script should accept the bytes written by golang as the password.

---

Alternatively is actually a method for this in the `exec` package for the `Cmd` type.

1. Use **cmd** to execute your shell script
2. Input the password using **stdin**, or `cmd.StdinPip()`
3. Read the shells **output** using `cmd.CombinedOutput()`

> Cmd represents an external command being prepared or run.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdinPipe

```
cmd := exec.Command("cat")
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

go func() {
    defer stdin.Close()
    io.WriteString(stdin, "values written to stdin are passed to cmd's standard input")
}()

out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
```

> StdinPipe returns a pipe that will be connected to the command's standard input when the command starts. The pipe will be closed automatically after Wait sees the command exit. A caller need only call Close to force the pipe to close sooner. For example, if the command being run will not exit until standard input is closed, the caller must close the pipe.

Also, your `cmd` arguments shouldn't combine clone and the url, try instead

```
cmd := exec.Command(cmdb, "clone", url)
```

Comment: i've try but doesn t seems to work : https://play.golang.org/p/Ffm3q5h636 thks btw

Comment: Hi, is it not working because you're using the play ground? Or is it not working on your machine?

Comment: not working on my machine , i have on my computer i doubt they have git on the playground :)

Comment: If you don't check for the error on CombinedOutput, I get     git: 'clone https://bb@gitlab.com/bb/fzgs.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: i've got this  : go run gitclone.go 
Password for 'https://bb@gitlab.com': it asks me for the password :/ (thks again btw)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to send the password before Git asks you
to do so.

And the way Git asks for password depends on whether [credential](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcredentials.html) helper is set. If the credential helper is not set, or doesn't return a password, the user is asked for input.

### Solution #1: Include Password into URI

In most cases (at least with Github and Bitbucket) the Git server accepts
credentials passed via HTTPS URI, e.g. `https://user:password@domain.com/repo.git`.

```
cmd := exec.Command("git", "clone", "https://bb:PASSWORD@gitlab.com/bb/fzgs.git")

env := os.Environ()
env = append(env, "GIT_ASKPASS=")
cmd.Env = env

var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out

err := cmd.Run()
```

### Solution #2: Custom Credential Helper

Another way is to make a credential helper script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash -
printf '%s\n' 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
```

and pass it via `GIT_ASKPASS`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("git", "clone", "https://bb@gitlab.com/bb/fzgs.git")

env := os.Environ()
env = append(env, "GIT_ASKPASS=/path/to/fzgs-askpass.sh")
cmd.Env = env

var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out

err := cmd.Run()
```